# Difference between &Struct{} vs Struct{}

Tags: pointers, struct, go, initialization, difference

Is there a reason why I should create a struct using `&StructName{}` instead of `Struct{}`? I see many examples using the former syntax, even in the [Effective Go Page](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#composite_literals) but I really can not understand why.

Additional Notes:
I'm not sure whether I explained my problem well with these two approaches so let me refine my question.

I know that by using the `&` I will recieve a pointer instead of a value however I would like to know why would I use the `&StructName{}` instead of the `StructName{}`. For example, is there any benefits of using:

```
func NewJob(command string, logger *log.Logger) *Job {
    return &Job{command, logger}
}
```

instead of:

```
func NewJob(command string, logger *log.Logger) Job {
    return Job{command, logger}
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well, they will have different behavior. Essentially if you want to modify state using a method on a struct, then you will need a pointer, otherwise a value will be fine. Maybe an example will be better:

```
package main
import "fmt"



type test_struct struct {
  Message string
}

func (t test_struct)Say (){
   fmt.Println(t.Message)
}

func (t test_struct)Update(m string){
  t.Message = m; 
}

func (t * test_struct) SayP(){
   fmt.Println(t.Message)
}

func (t* test_struct) UpdateP(m string)  {
  t.Message = m;
}

func main(){
  ts := test_struct{}
  ts.Message = "test";
  ts.Say()
  ts.Update("test2")
  ts.Say() // will still output test

  tsp := &test_struct{}
  tsp.Message = "test"
  tsp.SayP();
  tsp.UpdateP("test2")
  tsp.SayP() // will output test2

}
```

And you can run it here [go playground](http://play.golang.org/p/TwNPiRelIT)

Answer (score 7):

**Assuming you know the general difference between a pointer and a value:**

The first way allocates a struct and assigns a pointer to that allocated struct to the variable `p1`.

```
p1 := &StructName{}
```

The second way allocates a struct and assigns a value (the struct itself) to the variable `s`.
Then a pointer to that struct may be assigned to another variable (`p2` in the following example).

```
s := StructName{}
p2 := &s
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply however that's not my problem. I updated the question.